# elasticsearch - how to aggregate and filter by multiple rows

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data.

[image]

How can I query all countries that have currency 1 and 2?

The country can have multiple rows with the same currency (so count, can't help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter queries by desired currencies and aggregate them with a term aggregation.
The tricky part is force Elasticsearch to get all possible countries. This can be done using size=0 parameter in terms aggregation

```
currencies_criteria = [1,2]

elasticsearch_query = {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must" : [
                        {
                            "term": {"currency" : currencies_criteria}
                        }
                    ]

                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "country_count" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "country",
                #https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts
                "size"  : 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the sample execution of this answer in [this notebook](https://github.com/xecgr/stackoverflow_answers/blob/master/elasticsearch%20-%20how%20to%20aggregate%20and%20filter%20by%20multiple%20rows.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What does the size do? it works without it too?

Comment: Can I filter the results with doc count different than X

Comment: It can be done with Elasticsearch>=2.0 . https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Comment: if you specify size, only 10 are returned. 0 is special value that forces count all fields' possible values (well, Integer.MAX_VALUE, that's almost the same): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size